# Get combobox item tag

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Confused on why I am getting this error:

`Combobox` items:

```
private readonly string[] cbTexts = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "(Cleare)" };
```

dynamic `comboboxes`:

```
private void comboOptions()
        {
            cmb = new ComboBox[countWaiters];
            int width = 100;
            int height = 20;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
            {
                newBox = new ComboBox();         
                newBox.Text = "(Request)";          
                newBox.Size = new Size(width, height);
                newBox.Location = new Point(0, (i * height));
                cmb[i] = newBox;
                cmb[i].SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cmb_SelectedIndexChanged);
                foreach (string cbText in cbTexts)
                {
                    cmb[i].Items.Add(cbText);
                }

                pnlRequests.Controls.Add(newBox);
            }            
        }
```

`SelectedIndexChanged` event for the `comboboxes`:

```
void cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ComboBox senderCmb = (ComboBox)sender;

           int row = (int)senderCmb.Tag;
           //this is where the program crashes
           //more code located here that does something
         }
```

Error:
Note: Some method names have been changed from this image but does not effectanything
[image]

Comment: I can't see where you're setting the tag property, so no surprise that it's NULL (hence getting the error when trying to cast to an int).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set the `Tag` property anywhere in the given code, and I can't see why you need to. I suspect you want to get the current `SelectedIndex`:

```
int row = senderCmb.SelectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing line by me, silly mistake to make:

```
cmb[i].Tag = i;
```